# Spring AOP -to populate model data

Tags: spring-aop

Question 1:
Is it a good practice to use Spring AOP to populate\create the model in a portlet MVC environment? We have used Spring AOP extensively for populating\creating the Model object from an external source. Is AOP costly in-terms of performance when used very-extensively for such things as query execution, etc. I was informed AOP is good for crosscutting concerns and populating model data does not seem like a crosscutting concern, rather a main concern. I will be grateful for any guidance in this regard.

Question 2: I have a point-cut like so :

```
@Pointcut("execution(* getSomething(..))")
```

I have a class like so:

```
  Class Aclass extends ASuper{

     Somedata getSomething(String str){
         super.getSomething(str);
      }
    }
```

The ASuper has the getSomething method as well, how many times the aspect for the point-cut will execute once or twice?
I am thinking twice but a bit confused here hence the question. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: You usually have a reason to be using AOP, i.e. a concern you are trying to separate.   If you can not identify that reason you are probably applying AOP incorrectly.

Comment: Hi Darryl, thx for the response. I understand we can use AOP for logging, profiling, transaction-management, concerns that are like non-functional-requirement that can applied to whole modules. hmmm... that is what I was afraid of that AOP has been used wrongly for something that does that apply across a module. Is there a penalty in-terms of performance if we stick with this? Thx.

Comment: Yes there is additional performance penalty but it is unlikely to make a different to your application.  Transational management is usually done with the @Transational annotation.  I do not understand why you are putting AOP in now when it should be simple to add later, i.e. it sounds like you are paying an upfront development cost to add/include/configure it when you are not sure why/when/where you are going to need it. Your questions/comments sound like the blind leading the blind i.e. you do not sound like someone that should have authority to make a decision either which way.

Comment: We have already used AOP for creation and update of Model in the MVC pattern. What I am trying to figure out here is whether we did an anti-pattern and need to change or live with it and if we do live with what is the cost in terms performance that we need to tolerate, that is what I asked this question. Thx anyway.